# Jquery removeClass method

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have main div with an ID of `mvrContentFormDiv`. Inside there, there are 4 child div's with IDs of `reportFileURL`, `UploadReportDate`, `reportTitle` & `reportImageURL`.

Each of these have a class of `error`. Right now I am removing that class individually using the following code, but would like to use `removeClass` from the parent DIV.

```
$("#reportFileURL").removeClass("error");
$("#uploadReportDate").removeClass("error");
$("#reportTitle").removeClass("error");
$("#reportImageURL").removeClass("error");
```

Can anyone explain how I can do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children) method or [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector) to select them from the `mvrContentFormDiv`:

```
$('#mvrContentFormDiv > .error').removeClass('error');
```

or

```
$('#mvrContentFormDiv').children('.error').removeClass('error');
```

Answer (score 3):

unless you have other elements with that class elsewhere in the document that have to be untouched, you could simply do

```
$('.error').removeClass("error");
```

otherwise

```
$('<parentelement> .error').removeClass("error");
```

Answer (score 2):

try something like that:

```
$("#mvrContentFormDiv div").removeClass("error");
```

being 'mvrContentFormDiv' your parent id

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#mvrContentFormDiv .error").removeClass("error");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#mvrContentFormDiv").children().removeClass("error");
```